# Stacktrace TITLE in Firebase Crashlytics isn't deobfuscated

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

We have an android app in production and we use the Firebase Crashlytics.
Everything is good on Firebase Crashlytics page. The crashes stacktrace **is deobfuscated**. Only the stacktrace **TITLE** isn't deobfuscated. Look at the screenshot http://prntscr.com/xm0g6s . How to show human-readable TITLE? What is the problem and how to fix that?

### PLEASE DO NOT REFER ON SIMILAR ISSUES like "How to deobfuscate your stacktrace" because my stacktrace  actually is deobfuscated on Firebase Crashlytis page. Look at the screenshot

Dependencies I used:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
```

ProGuard is ON in the release build. My proguard-rules.pro file: https://gist.github.com/SergeyKharuk/f7bc59c328662fd39232c80bfd87eba8